# Why hot reload on my react project is so slow in docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, livereload, hot-reload

I need to wait for 10-20 seconds before seeing the updated result. I wonder why?
I used two ways to do the hot reload, one with docker run, the other with docker compose both are slow.
My folder structure is like:

```
--Folder
----node_modules/
----src/
----Dockerfile
----docker-compose.yaml
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:alpine AS development

# ENV CI=true

# Set the working directory within the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install pnpm globally within the container
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

# Install project dependencies using pnpm
RUN pnpm install

# Copy the rest of the application files to the container
COPY . .

EXPOSE ${PORT}

# Start the application
CMD ["pnpm", "start"]

# The builder stage
FROM development AS builder

RUN pnpm run build

# The production stage
FROM nginx:alpine AS production

COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

After building the image, I use the command to run the container with hot reload:

```
docker run -it  -p 3008:3008 -v $PWD:/app -v /app/node_modules imageName
```

Changes made in the host takes more than 10 seconds to show up.

Alternatively, I tried `docker compose up` as well, similar results, the change doesn't reflect on the UI immediately.
My compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}" 
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - exclude:/app/node_modules/
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
volumes:
  exclude:
```

What is wrong with my configs?

Comment: You're trying to do live development in a container with an isolated filesystem, possibly on a virtual machine as well (are you using Docker Desktop?).  This setup is known to be slow on some configurations.  As you've described it you don't seem to really need Docker at all; can you just use plain Node for day-to-day development?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your replay. I am learning docker and wanted to develop my project in a docker container. I am using the command line, no docker desktop installed. Your are right I don't need to use docker now, but I need it in future. Is there anything more I could provide to analyze the reason for the slowness?

Comment: Why do you think you'll need Docker; what benefits are you hoping to get from it?  It's very reasonable to use plain Node and other host-only tools for day-to-day development, and eventually deploy in Docker, without hard-wiring Docker into your development workflow.